# Facebook like button does not display correctly in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, cross-browser, facebook-like

I am using a like button from different social media site like `g+, facebook like, xing, and twitter`. `Facebook like button` works find in all browsers except in `IE7`. It displays like this image below: 
[image]

According to the forum, I got help to use `fb:like:width="115"`. However, it does not help to fix this browser issue. Also I have tried to use my own style with `!important` but it still does not overwrite because my style is called at the top of the page and it's at the bottom of the body of the page.

Does anyone know how to fix this without adding additional styles manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This above issue has been solved. I just add a like to the facebook opengraph and it works.

```
<html xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"
      xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Comment: Quite unclear how this solved your issue. What do you suggest we change in the HTML of a page to fix it for IE7, just add the OG namespace?

Answer (score 4):

You will find that Facebook no loner supports IE7 so the Like button will never be fixed to appear in IE7 correctly. It's broken because it's not compatible with IE7 (at least not the way FB has coded the Like button). You should get users to use a compatible browser (ideally IE9, Chrome or FF).

Comment: but I found it works on this website: http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381237-third-party-buttons#facebook-like

Answer (score 2):

### 3 Steps to Fix Facebook Like Button (with Count) for Internet Explorer 7

This example uses XFBML, since HTML5 is not yet supported by all browsers.

**Step 1 or 2 is usually where people go wrong**.

### Step 1

First check if you have included the Facebook namespace in the html tag:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

### Step 2

Now include this `meta` tag in the `head` section of your page:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

**How does this work?**

`IE=edge` forces IE to use the latest rendering engine (even in an intranet)

`chrome=1` forces Chrome Frame to use the latest IE rendering engine

### Step 3

Finally, include the Facebook XFBML & JavaScript SDK on your page:

**XFBML**

```
<fb:like send="false" layout="button_count" width="450" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

**JavaScript SDK**

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Comment: Please don't copy/paste duplicate content to several different pages.  If a question is a duplicate it needs to be closed as a duplicate.